# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting error while trying to run the code in jupyter notebook

I have tried to run the code by installing python separately, not using any python IDE

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b0fdfbdfd030> in <module>
    194 
    195 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 196     add_user()

<ipython-input-6-b0fdfbdfd030> in add_user()
    182         # when features of 3 files of speaker are concatenated, then do model training
    183         if count == 3:
--> 184             gmm = GMM(n_components = 16, n_iter = 200, covariance_type='diag',n_init = 3)
    185             gmm.fit(features)
    186 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter'
```

I need to get the output of the voice recorder

Comment: what happens when you remove `n_iter`? it's just not a parameter allowed for a GMM https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/gmm

Comment: error shows that `GMM` doesn't have option `n_iter` but you use it. Did you check documentation for `GMM` ?

Comment: this could help https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm_test.py

Comment: I have added max_iter instead if n_iter and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use an SKLearn [GMM](https://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html) object, but possibly giving the parameters for a [GausianMixture](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html) object instead, which arent supported in the GMM constructor.

The `n_iter` parameter, along with the `n_init` parameter are not valid parameters for the GMM object, so I would suggest checking the documentation for each (I linked them for you) and checking again which one you need to use, and setting the parameters accordingly.

EDIT: If its not SKLearn you're trying to use, please clarify this in your question regarding which package you're using here.